# Combining web services under one domain name.

Tags: mysql, dns, web, webserver, digital-ocean

What I want to do to combine a webs.com website with a Digital Ocean website so that my company website and my MySQL data bases are all reachable under one domain.  (E.g. YourDomain.com).  Is there any way this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible, but why do you want to do it?  The end user isn't contacting your DB directly, so why do you care what domain it resides on?  Why would you want to regress from having a distinct web server/DB architecture to one where they are on a shared server?

Comment: That's a good point, I just thought it would make things easier.  But I now see it from this new point of view.  I guess I won't do it then.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just host your mysql on a server and connect your site's db to the server IP. Provide some code dude or your actual setup